# The sum of an isogeny and its dual for the Frobenius homeomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

[image]

---

This is from page 150 of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves". Any my only questions is:

How you can conclude that $[a]=\phi+\hat{\phi}$?

I tried to use the formula on page 85 which is:

$[<\phi,\psi>]=[\deg(\phi+\psi)]-[\deg(\phi)]-[\deg(\psi)]=\hat{\phi}\circ \psi+\hat{\psi}\circ \phi$.

And i wanted to show that the LHS is equal to $a$ and the RHS is equal to $\phi+\hat{\phi}$ but it did not work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the multiplication by $a$ map on $E$. You have, by Theorem III.6.2,
$$
[a] = [1] - \left( ([1] - \phi) \circ ([1] - \hat{\phi}) \right ) + \phi \circ \hat{\phi}.
$$
Using that an isogeny is a homomorphism, you can expand it out to obtain
$$
[a] = [1] - [1] + \phi + \hat{\phi} - \phi \circ \hat{\phi} + \phi \circ \hat{\phi},
$$
which simplifies to $[a] = \phi + \hat{\phi}$.